# Pandas plot 2 subplots from 4 dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can plot many subplots from each series of a dataframe in 1 figure like this:

```
import pandas as pd

NG = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
dflist = []

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]


for n in NG:
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    dflist.append(df)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    dflist.append(df2)
    df = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 1)

df.plot(grid = 1, subplots = True, layout = (7,2), sharey = True)

print(df)
```

[image]

How can I combine every second plot? It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your previous question and this, you're looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]

for n in range(7):
    dflist = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    dflist.append(df)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    dflist.append(df2)
    df = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 1)
    ax = subplot(4, 2, n + 1)
    df.plot(ax=ax);
```

[image]

Comment: I get an (`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`) with (`ax = subplots(4, 2, n + 1)`) . Do i need to import Matplotlib? Spyder tells me that subplot is not defined

Comment: Ok, it works with matplotlib.pyplot. Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you vm :-)